# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found. and i use pip instal psycopg2 and the binary one

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, psycopg2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rfOT.png) I can't access tp psycopg2

no error and access to psycopg2 and not connected to django project show error no module found and server can't run and i use pip instal psycopg2 and the binary one
(myvenv) C:\Users\justp>python -c "import psycopg2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\justp\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2_*init*_.py", line 51, in 
from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.

(myvenv) C:\Users\justp>pip freeze

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)